# AWS: Cannot connect to Amazon instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, tcp

I had been trying to establish a MongoDB database with an exposed REST API (through Crest, then Sleepy Mongoose), but neither of these had been working. I tried to do a minimal sanity test of "Can I connect to that AWS machine or not?", so here's what I tried:

1) I set up a new Amazon instance (Ubuntu 14.04), and I made sure that all incoming TCP connections were accepted.

2) I tried running `sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80`.

3) This worked when logged into the machine and doing `curl http://localhost:80/` and `curl http://XX.XX.XX.XX:80/` (the machine's IP address substituted of course). However, on my local machine, the command just timed out.

I'm really looking forward to any guidance here, so I can hopefully go back to what I was originally doing (MongoDB, exposing a REST API, etc.). Really thankful for any suggestions since this has been driving me crazy!!

Comment: Did you go through this [troubleshooting page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)?

Comment: I had not previously, but I am successfully able to connect (login) to the instance, just not through a TCP/IP connection (which is what I meant in "Can I connect to that AWS machine or not?"). My apologies for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a security group issue.
When doing the `curl http://XX.XX.XX.XX:80/` on the machine itself, did you try the internal ip (172.x.x.x / 10.x.x.x / 192.x.x.x) or the external ip? 
Also, does the machine have an external ip assigned? (I'm guessing it does, otherwise ssh'ing to it would only be possible from another machine in the same subnet.)

Go to the AWS console, open the instance details and check the instance's security groups. Is port 80 open for the world (0.0.0.0/0) ?

Comment: I had been doing the internal IP address, which is probably why it was working; I didn't try the external IP address previously, but I tried it just now and it is hanging (as expected). Here's a screenshot of the current inbound rules: [screenshot](http://i66.tinypic.com/4g4652.png).

Comment: In unexplainable fashion, crest and all other TCP/IP reliant activities actually seem to be working now. Not sure whether it was just lag or my own fault, but thanks @bert-jan-schrijver!